# Oracle - Group By and Maintain Grouping Records

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregate-functions, oracle19c

How to maintain which all records are grouped and store it in separate table .

Base table :

[image]

After grouping the data on COLA , COLB And Summing it for COLC

```
Select COLA,COLB,SUM(COLC) 
FROM TAB2
```

And then generating key using Sequence .

[image]

Output which in need to maintain is as below .
How can we maintain such relationship considering there are 100 Columns for which group by is performed

Option 1: Tried below query to get the results but its does look efficient .

```
Select TAB1.KEY , TAB2.KEY 
FROM TAB1 
INNER JOIN TAB2 ON TAB1.COLA=TAB2.COLA 
AND TAB2.COLB=TAB2.COLB
```

[image]

Option 2 : While grouping and summing the data , store key in comma separated may be in clob column and then break it again in different sql .

```
RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,KEY,',').EXTRACT('//text()') ).GetClobVal(),',')
```

Comment: There is something that seems not well thought. If in tab1 some rows are inserted or deleted, then in tab2 the data will no longer show the sums corresponding to what currently is in tab1. I think then you should merge into tab2 using the select you have... But a merge on over 100 columns would lead to poor performance.

Comment: tab2 will run after data is ready in tab1 .

Answer (score 0):

So, if you need to join by N columns, out of which some happen to be nulls, better use standard_hash for joining.
Something like:

```
from table_1 a
join table_2 b on (
  standard_hash(a.col||'|'||a.col2||...||'|'||a.coln, 'SHA512')=
  standard_hash(b.col||'|'||b.col2||...||'|'||b.coln, 'SHA512')
  )
```

This function can also be used for creating an index. That's as much as I may suggest.
I see a big problem as to the table containing sum. Can you be certain it will be synchronized when there are some inserts, updates or deletes on the first table? I'd rather create a view or materialized view. Still, when you have large volumes of data there may be problems. Any partitioning? Well, you should know the aspects of your business better than me...

Comment: Yes my table is partition based on different file_id and i am running the procedure file by file only .